# Call Java functions dynamically based on strings

Tags: java, android, dynamic

I am building a java unit converter for an android application. I am offering the user a lot of different unit conversions, it ends up being 220 total conversions possible, 110 if you only count going in one direction. I.E. meters -> feet and feet -> meters would be two different conversions.

As of right now, I am planning on writing small methods for each conversion, so 220 in total ( I think this is probably the easiest way to go about it, even thought it will take some time). Now my question is, once I set 2 variables (convertFrom and convertTo) I want to know if it is possible to call the proper method dynamically? I could just create if/else if blocks, but that would just end up being an insane amount of code, and was hoping there was a better way to go about calling the correct method based off the 2 variables mentioned above. Any advice?

P.S. Sorry about no code here, I am only just getting started here and am just in the planning phase for this one.

Comment: Check out reflection.

Comment: Ya, I just found that and am looking into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a general idea, you could do something like this:

```
//invoking a static method (no instance is required)
public Object invoke(final Class<?> clazz, final String name, final Class<?>[] paramTypes, final Object[] args){
    return invoke(null, name, paramTypes, args);
}

//invoking a method on an object (instance is required)
public Object invoke(final Object instance, final Class<?> clazz, final String name, final Class<?>[] paramTypes, final Object[] args) throws Exception{
    assert clazz != null && name != null : "clazz || method == null";
    assert paramTypes.length == args.length : "paramTypes.length != args.length";
    Method method;
    try{
        //to check if the method has been overridden or not
        method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(name, paramTypes);
    }catch(NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex){
        //if method doesn't exist, exception is thrown
        method = clazz.getMethod(name, paramTypes);
    }
    //if method is protected or private
    if(!method.isAccessible())
        method.setAccessible(true);
    return method.invoke(instance, args);
}
```

If the method you are trying to invoke doesn't have any parameters, pass in an empty `Class<?>[]` (Likewise with the arguments except with an empty `Object[]`). The object returned from this method is the result of the method that just got invoked. If the method doesn't have a return type (`void`) then `null` is returned. The idea is to just basically cast the result to whatever it is that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would be best off using a switch block with an enum type.

You would create an enum like this:

```
public enum Units {
    METERS_TO_FEET("meters", "feet"), FEET_TO_METERS("feet", "meters") /**, etc...*/;

    private final String from;
    private final String to;

    public Units(final String from, final String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public static Units fromStrings(String from, String to) {
        if (from != null && to !=null) {
            for (Unit u : Unit.values()) {
                if (from.equalsIgnoreCase(u.from) && to.equalsIgnoreCase(u.to)) {
                    return u;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in your conversion method use a switch block:`

```
public int convert(String convertFrom, String convertTo, float fromVal, float toVal) {
    Units u = Units.fromStrings(convertFrom, convertTo);
    if(u == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input");
    }
    switch(u) {
    case METERS_TO_FEET :
        /** return meters to feet method on fromVal, toVal */
        break;
    case FEET_TO_METERS :
        /** return feet to meters method on fromVal, toVal */
        break;
    /** etc. */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an enum that converts every unit to one standard unit of measurement. Then you can just call convert to turn that standard unit of measurement into your new unit!

```
public enum UnitOfMeasure {
    // look at the constructor for the meaning
    // of the parameter
    UNIT1 (1.01),
    UNIT2 (1.02),
    // ...
    UNITX (2.00);

    // conversionFactor will convert each UNIT
    // type to your favorite UnitOfMeasure
    private final double conversionFactor;
    UnitOfMeasure(double conversionFactor) {
        this.conversionFactor = conversionFactor;
    }

    // have a constant for every unit type
    // to choose which unit to convert to
    public static final int UNIT_X = 0;
    public static final int UNIT_Y = 1;
    // ... etc.

    double convert(double value, int convertTo) {
    // a newUnitConversionFactor to convert
    // from our favorite unit of measurement
    // to our desired unit
        double newUnitConversionFactor = -1;
        switch (convertTo) {
        case UNIT_X:
            newUnitConversionFactor = 1.00;
            break;
        case UNIT_Y:
            newUnitConversionFactor = 1.01;
            break;
        // ... etc.
        }
        return value*conversionFactor*newUnitConversionFactor;
    }
}
```

Then you could simply convert by choosing a unit to convert from and a unit to convert to. For example, if I want to convert 5.00 of UNIT1 to UNITX, I can simply use this:

```
UnitOfMeasure.UNIT1.convert(5.00, UnitOfMeasure.UNIT_X);
```

This way, you will also know if a request to convert to a type that you do not support is called because the switch will do nothing and the result will be negative.